# Как мне отобразить текст под картинкой?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Вот что хочу сделать: три или более картинок с текстом под ними, которые будут выравниваться по горизонтали(в данном случае использую flex).
Но я так понимаю, что тег

начинает тоже выравниваться, так как без flex'a текст распологается под картинкой.

Как мне сделать, чтобы картинки выровнились по горизонтали с текстом под ними?
Ограничиваю эти блоки border'oм, и желательно чтобы были отступы от краёв сайта(margin-left/right/top).[image: код]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Тут `div` получают флекс, как-бы... А он нужен только общему div... ему дается `class="flex"` и дальше в CSS, `.flex { display: flex; и прочее... }`

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, благодарю!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том что вы даете общему div'у свойства. То есть, свойства которые вы задали блоку div будут применяться для всех div'ов на странице. Сделайте обертку (wrapper). 
Примерно вот так

```css
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
.wrapper .left, .wrapper .center, .wrapper .right {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Form registration on JavaScript</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="left">
          <img src="" alt="Left image">
      </div>
      <div class="center">
          <img src="" alt="Center image">
      </div>
      <div class="right">
          <img src="" alt="Right image">
      </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Не забудьте вставить свой текст:)
P.S. В следующий раз для удобства кидайте фрагмент кода, а не картинку XD